# separate dict from list in pandas dataframe column into different dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
[{
"name":"game_time",
"type":"int",
"info":"millisecond count since start of game"
},
{
"name":"round",
"type":"int",
"info":"number of the current round when the even takes place or 0 if no round"
}]
```

my try:

specs: Dataframe containing args column the file sample is attached below

```py
specs['args'].apply(lambda x : x.split('},{')).to_frame()['args'].apply(pd.Series).apply(lambda x : x.str[2:])
specs['args'].apply(pd.Series)
```

[sample file](https://filebin.net/nobk2xlvx4d24hvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that the ast will help you in this case.Here is solution

### one version of result

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('test_.csv', header = None)
df

Out[1]:

           0
    0   [{"name":"game_time","type":"int","info":"mill...
    1   [{"name":"game_time","type":"int","info":"mill...
    2   [{"name":"game_time","type":"int","info":"mill...
    3   [{"name":"game_time","type":"int","info":"mill..

lst = [m for s in df[0] for m in literal_eval(s)]
lst

Out[2]:

[{'name': 'game_time',
  'type': 'int',
  'info': 'millisecond count since start of game'},
 {'name': 'round',
  'type': 'int',
  'info': 'number of the current round when the event takes place or 0  if no round'},
 {'name': 'level',
  'type': 'int',
  'info': 'number of the current level when the event takes place or 0     if no level'},
 {'name': 'description',.......


pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lst)

Out[3]:

                                                     info   name        type
    0   millisecond count since start of game               game_time   int
    1   number of the current round when the event tak...   round       int
    2   number of the current level when the event tak...   level       int
    3   the text or description of the instruction          description string
    ........
```

is it your desired result?

### another version of result

if you desire the same output like in your code, here is the example

```
lst1 = [literal_eval(s) for s in df[0]]
pd.DataFrame(lst1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the dataframe constructor

```
data = [{
"name":"game_time",
"type":"int",
"info":"millisecond count since start of game"
},
{
"name":"round",
"type":"int",
"info":"number of the current round when the even takes place or 0 if no round"
}]

print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

out:

```
                                                info       name type
0              millisecond count since start of game  game_time  int
1  number of the current round when the even take...      round  int
```